# Remove IHS from DIE, why so hard?

Tags: cpu, performance-tuning

I have a CPU that is very cheap, I decided to try to remove the IHS from the DIE to become experienced in tuning. But it is pretty hard. I surrounded the DIE with blades, the glue still hold the IHS on the DIE.
[image]
[image]
[image]

What can I do further more to remove the IHS?

Comment: ...what CPU is this, exactly? Some are *soldered* down. And removing the IHS is never supported nor a design goal, anyway, so there's no reason for them to be easy to remove.

Comment: Use a heat gun to melt the solder, but be aware that excessive heat can actually damage the part.

Comment: @Mokubai If it's soldered down though, I see no reason to remove the IHS.

Comment: @Bob  
Intel Xeon E5504 2 GHz 4 (AT80602000801AA) Prozessor

Comment: @JMY1000 neither do I, but then I'm not the one trying to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nehalem and Westmere Xeons (N55xx/N56xx) are soldered to the IHS. [You'll need to heat up the solder before you can remove the chip.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoLkniC_JiE) With a soldered IHS though, the gains from such a removal are much more minimal, and I would strongly discourage removing the IHS.

Comment: Did you open every Nehalem and Westmere CPUs? I mean, where did you know? Is there a table? Any official source? How can I get the information what CPU is soldered?

Comment: No. I Googled various Nehalem and Westmere CPUs (and the 1366 i7s) and looked around to see if anyone had tried to delid them. It's the same for any other CPU AFAIK, Intel doesn't officially provide this for obvious reasons, and I couldn't find a comprehensive table. The only list I found gave up after the i7 975, but that's new enough for you, and really new CPUs there's lots of info on.